# Change orientation of turns of a trajectory

Tags: calculus, geometry, dynamical-systems, physics, mathematical-physics

Consider a robot following the dynamical system $R_B'=R_B\exp(\omega_B^{\times}), v_W'=R_B\alpha_B + g_W$, where $R_B\in SO(3), v, \alpha, \omega, g \in \mathbb{R}^3$, and $\omega^\times$ is the skew symmetric matrix associated to $\omega$. $v_B$ means a vector in the frame $B$ described by $R_B$, so that $v$ in the "world" frame is $v_W = R_B v_B$.

This robot is thus moving with angular velocity $\omega$, with non gravitational acceleration $\alpha$. $g$ is the known constant gravity vector and *I am given $\alpha_B, \omega_B, R_B$*.

Here is what I would like to formalize, and do:  suppose the robot is turning right, and rotating the head clockwise. What should I do to have the robot going left, and turning the head counterclockwise, e.g. follow the same trajectory, but flipped around, say, the $y$ axis?

#### Option 1

... somehow modifying $\omega, \alpha$. *It is very important that the new $\hat{\alpha}, \hat{\omega}$ have an expression in the new moving frame $C$ that is a combination of $\alpha_B, \omega_B, R_B$ (in the sense of sums, matrix products...).*

For instance, call $F$ the matrix flipping the world's $y$ axis: to turn the other way around, I apply $F$ to the axis of rotation and the flip its sign, to properly tilt the axis, and reverse the sign of rotation. This is done in the world frame, so, we have $\hat{\omega}_W = -F\omega_W$, hence, $\hat{\omega}_C=-R_C^TFR_B\omega_B$

The problem already is that this way I have to know $R_C$ and this is not something I possess.

#### Option 2

... somehow changing the world frame into $\hat{W}$, a change of point of view, so to say. This new world frame might be a flip of the original one as before, or a rotation of it around its $x$ axis, of an angle of $\pi$. However, the robot itself is still "feeling" as it is turnign the same way as before, and this is something that is not desirable for my application. *The robot should really feel a different angular velocity and acceleration.* Also, the robot has to satisfy the system of the beginning, so, *flipping gravity is not allowed*.

---

Do you have any (other) idea? In italic I layed down some data/constraints that I have. Feel free to ask clarifications in case!

Comment: Why don't just replace the vector $\omega$ with $-\omega$ ?

Comment: Because then the robot walks towards the left and then tilts the head towards the right. Then one should modify the acceleration in world frame, but this also would imply a gravity flip, right?

Comment: How many degrees of freedom do you have in this setup ?

Comment: The robot can move in all directions, and look in all directions (does this answer your question or did I misunderstand?)

Comment: No, it does not.  My question is how many motors (also known as actuators) does this robot have ?  In other words, how many generalized coordinates (like prismatic displacements, or angular displacements ) does the robot have ?

Comment: I am not able to fully answer the question, I'll try instead to describe the robot as good as I can...
It can be a car or drone with the intertial sensor mounted on top, or a person with the sensor mounted on the head...